# How do select customerIDs where transactionDate is within 90 days of lastVisitDate in SQL-hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have three columns: customerID, transactionDate, and lastVisitDate. CustomerID is an int, and the other two fields are of the datatype timestamp.  I would like to know how I can select the customers on a given day (the transactionDate) who have been in the store no more than 90 days ago...so 90 days or less. I should mention that I'm doing this in hive.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think this is all you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where transactiondate < date_add(lastvisitdate, 90);
```

This assumes that `lastvisitdate` is always before `transactiondate` -- which seems like a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM table
WHERE LastVisitDate >= DATEADD(dd, -90, GetDate())
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
```

Something like this should do it.

Comment: What is the dd?